# Impossible to boot due to corrupted and/or missing logical volume

Tags: boot, centos, lvm

I am facing a big LVM trouble with a cluster I have to administrate after departure of our beloved colleague. The cluster has 10 nodes under CentOS 6.5 with a single volume group. On top of this group, he defined (I guess) several logical volume, including `lv_root` and `lv_home`. I have to say I never used LVM or so. While I was configuring network due to change in the routes, I decided to reboot the system and here the troubles begin:

First, the system refuse to boot because a `fsck` failure on `/dev/vg_shared-lv_root`. It proposed to log as root, which I did, and I ran `e2fsck` on it and it seemed to work. After that, I `ctr-alt-suppr` to restart that node and then, system refused to boot due to a corrupted file-system error on `/dev/vg_shared-lv_home`. But I cannot find any `lv_home` inside `/dev/vg_shared`, while `lv_root` is here.

I seach for troubleshooting guides that all propose to use tools like `vgscan`, which I can't use with error `File-based locking initialisation failed`

My main concern is with the data on that filesystem, which represent several months of computations: is there a way to access that `lv_home`?
My second concern is reparing that file-system, but I have no idea where to start.

I don't know what to tell more. I could give as much details as needed to get some help... Thank you for any hint.

Best regards

Antoine

I cannot run things like `vgscan` due to file system mounted in read-only mode.

In fact, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What is the output of pvs;vgs;lvs ?  Also, can you describe what kind of disks you have and how they are connected?

Comment: Hi; all three `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs` yield `File-based locking initialisation failed`. Each node has its own hard-drive over both ethernet and infiniband network.

Comment: Did you run it as root?

Comment: yes, I'm logged in as root. At boot, the system complains about `fsck` error and urges to log as root to correct. I only have acces to the root filesystem (that seems to be logical volume `lv_root` onto a logical volume group `vg_shared`). But I cannot acces other logical volumes, in particular the `lv_home`

Comment: The error you are getting is likely because the mounted filesystem (at least /var) is read-only (which might be due to corruption of the filesystem). Try using a live filesystem based boot.

Comment: I could access the cluster today. Booting from live centos 7 usb key, I could activate all the lvs that now appear with lvscan as well as in lsblk, but fail to mount them. From dmesg, I see I/O error, seems disk is corrupted. Tried a fsck -y that turned file sytem to ext2 on the first run (after some corrections) and turned back to ext3 on the second run (after far more corrections) !?! Any idea how to procede then? Will make a snapshot with TestDisk tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Start with your last disk 1mages.

- First, boot from other media, e.g. a [live CentOS USB](https://www.fosslinux.com/6880/how-to-create-a-bootable-centos-live-usb-drive-on-windows.htm) flash drive.
- Second, salvage the most recent files since the last backup, putting them on other drives.
- Third, check the cluster for bad drives, e.g. using S.M.A.R.T. data and actual media test. Replace any filing drives.
- Fourth, restore the last disk images.
- Fifth, restore the files salvaged in the second step.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.